# Unable to run an interactive shell script using conda run

Tags: bash, conda

I have this script "/home/prod/test.sh"

```
#!/bin/bash
echo Hello, who am I talking to?
read varname
echo It\'s nice to meet you $varname
```

I was expecting that when I run this command

```
conda run -n myenv /home/prod/test.sh
```

I will see a prompt waiting for me to enter the value for varname , instead I got

```
(base) prod@dev-box:~$ conda run -n reportz /home/prod/test.sh
Hello, who am I talking to?
It's nice to meet you

(base) prod@dev-box:~$
```

Would very much appreciate a response detailing, how I can use conda to run an inetractive shell script ?

[Edit]

Replaced `read varname` with `read -r varname < /dev/tty`

It did wait for my input, but without displaying the output resulting from the echo statement `echo Hello, who am I talking to?`

Solution I'm looking for - the script should run with `conda run` command exactly as it would in a typical shell env.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `conda run` command defaults to buffering I/O. To have interaction, one needs to include the `--no-capture-output` flag.

```bash
conda run -n myenv --no-capture-output /home/prod/test.sh
```

This feature was introduced in Conda v4.9.0 ([Change Log](https://github.com/conda/conda/blob/4.9.0/CHANGELOG.md)).

Comment: So, I ran

`(base)prod@dev-box:~$ conda run -n myenv --no-capture-output /home/prod/test.sh`


and got this output


`usage: conda [-h] [-V] command ...`


`conda: error: unrecognized arguments: --no-capture-output`


FYI: conda version I'm using `conda 4.8.3`

Comment: @serengiti you'll need to update (`conda update -n base conda`). This feature was introduced in 4.9.0.

Comment: Thanks @merv , referring to this [https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/9412#issuecomment-719759077](Related Git issue conda/issues/9412). This command line option is available only 4.9.0 onwards. The issue is still noted as "open"

Comment: Not sure why the issue is still open - but it works perfectly fine for me on **linux-64** and **osx-64** platforms.

Comment: Upgraded and it worked. Thanks a lot. Accepting your response.